# Customize ListView in AlertDialog

Tags: android, listview

Hey, I have a ListView that I want to be displayed into an AlertDialog, I have 2 problems:
1. The text is displayed in the left side, I want it to be in the center
2. To choose an item, you have to select exactly the text of the row.. How to make it possible to select the item even if selecting outside the text in the same row?
You can see in the picture that the orange highlight is on the text itself only rather than the whole row..:
[image]

Code:

LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mContext);

```
            ListView lv = new ListView(mContext);

            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, BooksOptions));

            Builder alert;
            alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);              

            layout.addView(lv);
            alert.setView(layout);
```

Comment: paste code for your layout simple_list_item_1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're utilizing the standard Android list item layout, `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`. Instead, create your own item layout based on that layout and set the properties appropriately.

`<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
/>`

Note that you're also not setting layout properties on the `ListView` itself. Ensure that you specify it to have it `match_parent` for width as well in your layout.